# Java action sending 2 information

Tags: jsp

```
 <form action="/member/detailhandler.jsp?tid=<%=tid %>"  class="login-form">
 <input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="height:200px;"     style="width: 200px;" 
 placeholder="your writing here" /><br/>
 <button>submit</button>
 </form>
```

This from action only sends name="text_name"

```
  /member/detailhandler.jsp?text_name=sdfdsf
```

And does not send the information about Tid. 
If I want to send both information which line should I  have to fix?

Comment: If you change it to a post form you'll get both the tid and the text_name, tid will be GET and text_name will be POST. You can't pass query params (tid) and form params. Either put tid as a hidden input or change to a post form like i mentioned

Comment: GOT IT THANK YOU MAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it as a hidden field as follows

```
<form action="/member/detailhandler.jsp"  class="login-form" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" id="tId" name="Tid" value="<%=tid%>"/>
   <input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="height:200px;" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="your writing here" /><br/>
   <button>submit</button>
</form>
```